# VSIX loads in experimental instance (debug) but not in non-experimental

Tags: sdk, visual-studio-2015, vsix

I've rebuilt this project twice from the ground up, and I can't figure out why my VSIX' menu items and Options pages are being loaded through debug mode but not by installing the .VSIX file manually.  Nothing shows in the Output window and I'm not sure where to look for VS logging of this kind of stuff.

THIS WAS WORKING before, but stopped about a week ago.

I even created a Hyper-V W8.1 VM and installed VS2015 (final release) and installed the VSIX and it just doesn't seem to load at startup unless I'm debugging.

This is VS2015 final.

My source code is at https://github.com/cbordeman/Mvvm-Tools.

Comment: 1) Does your extension appear in Tools > Extensions and Updates window? 2) Is it enabled? 3) Does it appear in Help > About window? 4) Do it commands appear in Tools > Options, Environment > Keyboard, Show commands containing? 5) Are its command executed when typed in View > Other Windows > Command Window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.  I was missing an Asset in my Assets section of my .vsixmanifest:

```
<Assets>
    <Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.VsPackage" d:Source="Project" d:ProjectName="%CurrentProject%" Path="|%CurrentProject%;PkgdefProjectOutputGroup|" />
</Assets>
```

Comment: If there is a way to mark your finding as answer, please do that. It took couple of minutes to figure out this thing. Nice finding though.